# How do I restrict AWS Amplify DataStore's event subscriptions to those to which user has access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, datastore

When I use AWS Amplify DataStore in my app I get multiple errors of the form

```
[WARN] 10:54.853 DataStore - subscriptionError, Connection failed: {"errors":[{"errorType":"Unauthorized","message":"Not Authorized to access onDeleteSomeModel on type SomeModel"}]}
```

It appears that DataStore generates the subscriptions for onCreate, onUpdate & onDelete of all models, including those to which the currently logged in user has no access.

How do I prevent this, and limit DataStore's subscriptions to only those models and events to which a user has access (and why isn't that the obvious default behavior)?